# How to export another object along with express router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am not able to export another object along with the express router.I face the error **"TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object"**
This problem exists only when I have to export another object with the express router.

here is the code that i have written

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const session = require('express-session');
const User=require('../models/User');




var curr_user=""


const articles=[{
  title:'Test articles 1',
  createdAt:Date.now(),
  description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt, mauris in pulvinar interdum, neque justo malesuada nulla, nec vestibulum nisi nulla vel sapien. Proin mollis nulla sed urna placerat, in pharetra felis ultrices. Donec vel semper turpis. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse posuere scelerisque lacus, at blandit tellus porta vel. Fusce sed lacus finibus, posuere felis eget, bibendum felis.'

},{
title:'Test articles 2',
createdAt:Date.now(),
description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt, mauris in pulvinar interdum, neque justo malesuada nulla, nec vestibulum nisi nulla vel sapien. Proin mollis nulla sed urna placerat, in pharetra felis ultrices. Donec vel semper turpis. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse posuere scelerisque lacus, at blandit tellus porta vel. Fusce sed lacus finibus, posuere felis eget, bibendum felis ncidunt, mauris in pulvinar interdum, neque justo malesuada nulla, nec vestibulum nisi nulla vel sapien. Proin mollis nulla sed urna placerat, in pharetra felis ultrices. Donec vel semper turpis. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse posuere scelerisque lacus, at blandit tellus porta vel. Fusce sed lacus finibus, posuere felis eget, bibend.'

},{
title:'Test articles 3',
createdAt:Date.now(),
description:'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt, mauris in pulvinar interdum, neque justo malesuada nulla, nec vestibulum nisi nulla vel sapien. Proin mollis nulla sed urna placerat, in pharetra felis ultrices. Donec vel semper turpis. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse posuere scelerisque lacus, at blandit tellus porta vel. Fusce sed lacus finibus, posuere felis eget, bibendum felis.'

}]


const router = express.Router();

// Configure middleware
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
router.use(
  session({
    secret: 'mysecret', // Set a secret key for session encryption
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

// Define routes
const requireAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.session && req.session.authenticated) {
    console.log(`sessions is ${curr_user}`)
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/register/login');
  }
};

router.get('/posts', requireAuth, (req, res) => {
  

res.render('articles/index',{articles:articles});
});

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login');
});

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    console.log(`user is ${user}`)
    if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password))) {
      req.session.authenticated = true;
      curr_user=user.name
      res.redirect('/register/posts');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/register/login');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.redirect('/register/posts');
  }
});

router.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
  res.render('signup');
});

router.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
  const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hashedPassword
  });
  user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/register/signup');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/register/login');
    }
  });
});

module.exports= {router,articles};
```

I tried to search for alternative 3rd party libraries that could do this job.But did not work either.

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: the problem is probably how you are _importing/requiring_ it, so include that code